# Incrementing a value within a print statement

Tags: python, loops, printing

I'd like to condense this section of the code below.

```
    Selector()
    print(week[0], "A:", x, "B:", y, "C:", z)
    Selector()
    print(week[1], "A:", x, "B:", y, "C:", z)
    Selector()
    print(week[2], "A:", x, "B:", y, "C:", z)
    Selector()
    print(week[3], "A:", x, "B:", y, "C:", z)
    Selector()
    print(week[4], "A:", x, "B:", y, "C:", z)
    Selector()
    print(week[5], "A:", x, "B:", y, "C:", z)
    Selector()
    print(week[6], "A:", x, "B:", y, "C:", z)
```

I'd like to make a simple loop to call the function then the print statement and increment the value in "week[ ]" by 1 for every time it's printed.

Full code:

```
import random
import calendar

week = []
for i in calendar.day_name:
  week.append(i)

listA = ["Patsy", "Spam", "Eggs", "Foo"]

def Selector ():
  listB = [i for i in listA]

  random.shuffle(listB)
  for i in listB:
    global x
    x = i
    listB.remove(i)
    break

  random.shuffle(listB)
  for i in listB:
    global y
    y = i
    listB.remove(i)
    break

  random.shuffle(listB)
  for i in listB:
    global z
    z = i
    listB.remove(i)
    break

Selector()
print(week[0], "A:", x, "B:", y, "C:", z)
Selector()
print(week[1], "A:", x, "B:", y, "C:", z)
Selector()
print(week[2], "A:", x, "B:", y, "C:", z)
Selector()
print(week[3], "A:", x, "B:", y, "C:", z)
Selector()
print(week[4], "A:", x, "B:", y, "C:", z)
Selector()
print(week[5], "A:", x, "B:", y, "C:", z)
Selector()
print(week[6], "A:", x, "B:", y, "C:", z)
```

Which gives the desired result:

```
Monday A: Spam B: Patsy C: Eggs
Tuesday A: Eggs B: Foo C: Spam
Wednesday A: Spam B: Patsy C: Eggs
Thursday A: Eggs B: Patsy C: Foo
Friday A: Spam B: Foo C: Patsy
Saturday A: Patsy B: Eggs C: Spam
Sunday A: Patsy B: Foo C: Spam
```

I've tried this loop:

```
def schedule():
  for int in week [0]:
    if int < 7:
      print(week[0], "A:", x, "B:", y, "C:", z)
```

I get: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'list'. I have no clue where to go from here.

I am new to programming so perhaps there is a better way to go about all of this. I am open to suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to iterate over the first element of the list, not the list itself. Further, you don't need an index at all; iterating over the list gives you the elements themselves.

```
def schedule():
    for w in week:
        Selector()
        print(w, "A:", x, "B:", y, "C:", z)
```

You can simplify this greatly, though. If you just want three random elements from `listA`, do

```
for w in week:
    x, y, z = random.sample(listA, 3)
    print(f"{w} A: {x} B: {y} C: {z}")
```